# Finding the element place in a split array

Tags: javascript

How do I find the place of an element in a split array with JS? For example, pretend I have the array, `var str = "a, b, c, d, e, f, g"` and after I split an array with `str.split(', ')`, I want to find the place of e (by place I mean that "a" would be 1, "b" would be 2, "c" would be 3, and so on). How do I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Find the [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) the element in the array and add `1` to get its position. If `indexOf` returned `-1` then the element was not in your array.

Comment: `str.split(', ').indexOf('e')+1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
var str = 'a, b, c, d, e, f, g'
var arr = str.split(',')
console.log(arr.indexOf('a') + 1)
```